# PHP display sub sub item of json decoded array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using PHP to interact with an API and I am having trouble displaying the value of a sub sub item in a json decoded array that is a response from an API request. I can successfully display all of the array data but I can't display the specific value I am looking for which is the product image link.

I am trying to access 'data->images->link' from the response format below:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "country": "string",
  "page_count": 0,
  "page_current": 0,
  "page_size": 0,
  "total_items": 0,
  "data": {
    "code": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "categories": [
      "string"
    ],
    "colours": "string",
    "dimensions": [
      "string"
    ],
    "sizing": [
      {
        "sizing_line": "string"
      }
    ],
    "materials": "string",
    "specifications": "string",
    "branding_options": [
     {
       "print_type": "string",
       "print_description": "string"
      }
    ],
    "packaging": "string",
    "carton": {
      "length": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "weight": "string",
      "quantity": 0
    },
    "full_colour": 0,
    "mix_and_match": 0,
    "image_count": 0,
    "images": [
      {
        "link": "string",
        "name": "string"
      }
    ],
     "product_wire": "string",
     "pricing": [
        {
        "type": "string",
        "primary_price_description": "string",
        "less_than_moq": "string",
        "prices": [
         {
           "quantity": 0,
           "price": 0
        }
       ],
        "additional_costs": [
          {
            "description": "string",
            "unit_price": 0,
            "setup_price": 0
          }
        ],
        "pricing_comment": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help or advice is much appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

If you use `json_encode` as below then you must need to write in object format:

```
$test1 = json_decode($test);
print_r($test1->data->images[0]->link);
```

If you use add "true" as 2nd parametet to `json_decode` then you can access it as array as below:

```
$test2 = json_decode($test, true);
print_r($test2['data']['images'][0]['link']);
```

check this way and let me know if you still have an issue.